# Why isn't this.setState working here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  groupRef.child(childSnapshot.key).once("value", (snap) => {
    this.setState.bind({
      expenses: this.state.expenses.concat(snap.val()),
    });
  })
})
```

The error which I get is

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setState')
```

The state has been declared in the following way

```
constructor(props) {
  super (props);
  this.state = {
    expenses: [],
  };
}
```

Comment: in which function are you doing this.setState? if it is not lifecylce method and being called from another component you need to bind that perticular function.

Comment: When I bind it I get a type error

Comment: can you share that code?

Comment: this.expenses = this.expenses.bind(this);   this is the way I binded it

Comment: I have now put it in a lifecycle method and removed the binding but I am still geting the same error

Answer (score 5):

It's because you're not calling or using bind correctly and you are referencing `this` which is different in the context you created by calling forEach with a traditional function callback. The first argument to bind is the context not arguments.

In this case just avoid it and use arrow functions so `this` is still your component reference.

```
snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
  groupRef.child(childSnapshot.key).once("value", snap =>
    this.setState(state => ({ expenses: [ ...state.expenses, snap.val()] }))
  );
});
```

Note that you should use the callback style of setState as above when referencing existing state, since setState is asynchronous by the time your state is set it might have changed especially when setting in a loop in an async callback.

Comment: That's not possible unless the context was already incorrect at the time of `snapshot.forEach`, but you didn't post the outer code so I don't know. Is that code executed from an event e.g. a click?